# Socket IO Wont Send Specific Text, Others Work Fine

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hello I'm writing an application that uses nodejs and socket io, Long story short its a social network with posting functionality etc.

For the most part the 'post' works fine you can type a message hit share (which sents it to the nodejs server via http post) where the record will be stored to the mongodb database, then socketio kicks in and sends the object to all the connected clients with permission to see the message.

This whole process works fine except for one specific message.

> July 16, 2014 is
>   National Corn Fritters Day
>   It’s National Corn Fritters Day! Corn fritters are savory bites of fried or baked corn batter—a mixture made with corn, egg, flour, milk, and melted butter. These treats can be eaten alone, served as a side, or enjoyed with a topping like syrup, powdered sugar, or jam.
>
> Although corn fritters originated in the South, many other cultures have come up with similar dishes. For example, in Asia “pakoras” are a popular snack. This dish is made with vegetables dipped in batter that are then deep-fried.
>
> To celebrate National Corn Fritters Day, head to your local Southern-style restaurant or grab your frying pan to cook up some homemade fritters!

This one message..... will not send via socket io I've inspected it with a character inspector and cant figure out why it wont send i've run it through control character strippers and still nothing.

here is the chunk of code that does the sending

```
                    io.to(tmpPost.metadata.createdby._id).emit('server_new_post', tmpPost)
```

I have verified that the line of code does in-fact execute and the record is stored to the database but this socket will not send a post object containing this text.

Comment: Are you sure the "—" isn't creating a problem? Can you try substituting that with a plain hyphen and trying again?

Comment: thanks for your reply galacto! I've  most certainly tried this I've even gone through and manually removed all the symbols which didn't work either. The one thing that did work was removing all the symbols and the two nearest characters and all 'new lines' which did work! that got me thinking maybe its control characters so i did some testing by removing those too and no luck! -kind regards